# Why XMLHttpRequest object property, status is 200 when the file not exist

Tags: ajax

Why status property is 200 when the url of the file is not correct:

```
var xhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.onload=function(){
 console.log(xhttp.status);
 }
 xhttp.open('GET','notexist.php',false);
 xhttp.send();
```

I don't have notexist.php on my server. but still status property returns  200!! ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `onload` runs on a *successful* completion. If you're in it, you can already assume a non-4xx status code (almost always 200).

That's not your real issue, though. (At worst, it means you're not handling errors properly.) Your real issue is that the status code represents the server's response when you visit `notexist.php`. If your server is returning a 200 response code (whether directly, or possibly by bouncing to an "error" page that is just a normal web page), then that's what your XMLHttpRequest will see, and errors will look like successes.

Ensure that page-not-found errors cause your server to return a 404 response code.